# Composer diagnose problema con HTTP y HTTPS con symfony2

Tags: symfony2, symfony, composer

Intente ejecutar un *composer install* en *symfony2*  y me genero

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                              
Could not scan for classes inside "/var/www/html/git/gestionresiduos/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/config" which doe  
s not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

Ejecutando el *composer diagnose* me genera el siguiente error:

```
Checking http connectivity to packagist: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
Checking https connectivity to packagist: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

Si ejecuto `php -r "readfile('http://www.google.com');"` me informa lo siguiente:

```
PHP Warning:  readfile(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  readfile(http://www.google.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in Command line code on line 1
```

Ejecute los siguientes comandos y pude resolver los problemas de conexion que me daba el *composer diagnose*

```
export https_proxy=10.7.24.218:3128
export http_proxy=10.7.24.218:3128
composer clearcache
composer clearcache
composer self-update --update-keys
(ingreso y copio desde la url: https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html)
```

Pero el *composer update* me informa lo siguiente:

```
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
 The "https://app.santafe.gob.ar/archivist/packages.json" file could not be   
  downloaded: failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through p  
 roxy
```

¿Como puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: que salida te da este comando: `php -r "readfile('http://www.google.com');"`?

Comment: Ahi edite el posteo y subi la respuesta del comando que me pasaste.

Comment: entoces la salida de tu internet es a traves de un proxy, no es un problema de composer si no de tu configuracion de internet

Comment: Igmer, me puede orientar en como configurarlo? muchas gracias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307600/php-composer-behind-http-proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi corriendo los siguientes comandos

```
export http_proxy=http://10.7.24.218:3128
export https_proxy=http://10.7.24.218:3128
export HTTP_PROXY=http://10.7.24.218:3128
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.7.24.218:3128
```

Recuerden reemplazar la *ip de su proxy* y el *puerto*